# Chrome using value rather than placeholder in an HTML form

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm using the following line in an HTML form:

```
<input type="text" value="rname" id="rname" name="rname" placeholder="NAME.........";>
```

In every browser I've tested except Chrome, the prefilled text in the field reads "NAME........." as desired.

But Chrome prints "rname", which investigation has shown it's getting from the value field.

What is the simplest way to alter this line so that it works on Chrome as well as the other browsers? I'm not even sure why (or whether) value, id, and name fields all need to be used, when they all have the same content.

All I need is for whatever the user types in the field to be picked up in PHP, which surely only needs one variable, not three? I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: you only need the ```name``` attribute to get the input value submitted by user, you can remove ```value``` attribute if you don't want a default value for the input, you can also remove ```type``` attribute since ```text``` is the default value, ```id``` is commonly used to connect input with label through the label ```for``` attribute, ```placeholder``` is just a place holder that tells the user information about the input, for example ```Search a product...```.

Comment: `placeholder` is visible only when `value` is empty.  It works the same in all modern browsers (not in old IE).

Comment: Thanks, Johnny and Alex. I thought I was going crazy when FF was insisting on displaying "Submit query" on the submit button even though those words aren't in the code, but it seems to print what it gets from the value field. I'm not sure why it needs a placeholder variable at all.